# Changing the hostname on WSL

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

sudo hostname XYZ does not seems to work in WSL.

I recently reinstalled Windows 10 and my wsl hostname is DESKTOP-XXXXXX. I'm trying to change it to something else. I tried the following:

```
sudo hostname wsl
```

I also changed `/etc/hostname` to "wsl" and changed `/etc/hosts` to "127.0.1.1 wsl.localdomain wsl".

Every time I restart WSL, it resets the hostname to the windows name. How do I change the wsl hostname permanently?

Comment: Have you tried to change the host system's name from `System --> Change Settings --> Change`? I am not sure, but it would make sense for WSL to update its hostname to match that of the host computer.

Comment: @ifconfig That worked, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, where is this system menu?

Comment: Because this is the top result on Google: To change independently from windows. In WSL do: `sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf`, add the lines `hostname = your-new-hcleaost-name`, and `generateHosts = false` under `[network]`, then in CMD on windows do `wsl --shutdown` to make it take effect. Source: https://www.srccodes.com/change-hostname-ubuntu-microsoft-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-wsl2-wsl-conf-unable-resolve-hosts-name-service-not-known-list-running-shutdown-vm-srccodes/

Comment: Andersen's comment should really be the acceptable answer!

Comment: create `/etc/wsl.conf` file and add the lines `[network]` `hostname = <hostname>` and `generateHosts = false`. Finally restart wsl2 from powershell with `wsl --shutdown`. Restart wsl2 to see the changes reflect.

Comment: you can edit /etc/wsl.conf like alex but leave generatedHost=true and add your hostname to windows hosts file to add your hostname

Comment: Andre comment is correct and the solution in the link worked for me

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try to change the host system's name from `System --> Change Settings --> Change`. In some sense, it makes sense for WSL to update its hostname to match that of the host computer.

Comment: I feel silly, for searching this up xD

Comment: It's not a silly question to wonder about, @NerdioN. It also makes perfect sense to me why someone would automatically assume that WSL isn't that attached to the host Windows OS like that.

Comment: I wanted to use the hostname in WSL to help distinguish between multiple distributions installed with WSL. I think I'll have to customise my prompt instead.

Comment: Someone would want to change the WSL distro's hostname to make it distinct from the host Windows machine. Wonder why would you suggest making changes in Windows to still reflect in the WSL distros.

Comment: I'd add it as an answer, but the question is locked. To change independently from windows. In WSL do: `sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf`, add the lines `hostname = your-new-hcleaost-name`, and `generateHosts = false` under `[network]`, then in CMD on windows do `wsl --shutdown` to make it take effect. Source: https://www.srccodes.com/change-hostname-ubuntu-microsoft-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-wsl2-wsl-conf-unable-resolve-hosts-name-service-not-known-list-running-shutdown-vm-srccodes/

Comment: @AndréC.Andersen That file doesn't exist on my WSL. Is it supposed to?

Comment: See official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config

Answer (score 24):

In Windows 10 Home 64-bit, Fall Creators Update edition (Version 1709, Build 16299.19) I used:

`Settings` ▸ `System` ▸ `About` ▸ `Rename this PC`

After that a restart is required.