# How can you change the hostname inside WSL without changing the PC name in Windows

Tags: debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a way to have a different hostname on WSL than the actual Windows PC name?

Is there a general way of doing this or is it specific to each distro (Ubuntu vs Debian for example)?

Note : A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44869410/changing-the-hostname-on-wsl) but the answers are either specific to Ubuntu, or just about changing the Windows PC name. I'm more interested in changing the WSL hostname *without changing the Windows PC name*

I tried

- hostname [newname] command, added to .bashrc (requires root)
- tried hostnamectl (fails)
- tried adding hostname = [hostname] in /etc/wsl.conf (doesn't work on Debian)

Answer (score 0):

In general, the way to change the hostname in most if not all linux distributions (including Ubuntu and Debian) is by modifying the `/etc/hosts/` and `/etc/hostname` files.

Find wherever your current name is mentioned and replace it with your desired one.

Note that those also require root privileges (run with `sudo`).